# Sitecore - Application Insights Telemetry - Custom properties

Tags: session-state, tracking, custom-field, application-insights

I am struggling with accomplishing the following scenario: I need to create a custom property for **Application Insights**, containing an identifier for the user (which is read from the data store at login time).

Went through several articles on the matter, but it does not seem to work.

I tried the following so far:

1. Implemented a custom telemetry initializer and loaded it in a Sitecore pipeline. The problem here is that I can't access the session object, as it's always **NULL**. After some research I realized that it is triggered before the session is even created, so then I went to the second option.
2. Tried to load the telemetry initializer in a `HttpRequestProcessor`, I was able to access the session, but the Initialize method is never triggered afterwards. Can't say I understand what is happening. I added the initializer as follows `TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new UserIdTelemetryInitializer([injected_service]))`, in the constructor of the processor, so it is only triggered once.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what exactly I am doing wrong? If you have a code example that works for you in a similar case, I would be grateful.

Let me know if you need additional information (might have been too brief about it).

**EDIT**

I am registering the pipeline from option 2 in a patch file as follows:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
<sitecore>
    <pipelines>
        <httpRequestProcessed>
            <processor type="[namespace].Pipelines.ApplicationInsights.UserIdTelemetryProcessor, [namespace]" resolve="true" />
        </httpRequestProcessed>
    </pipelines>
</sitecore>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Application Insights telemetry initializers are triggered before the Session_OnStart event occurs, so you need to register your custom telemetry initializer in the `Session_Start` method in the `Global.asax.cs` of your application.

##### Custom Telemetry Initializer

You probably already created this, but I am sharing here an example. Mine is inheriting one of the existing OOTB telemetry initializers and overrides the `OnInitializeTelemetry` method. In this way, you get easily access to the HttpContext object:

```
public class SitecoreSessionInitializer : SessionTelemetryInitializer
{
        /// <summary>Implements initialization logic.</summary>
        /// <param name="platformContext">Http context.</param>
        /// <param name="requestTelemetry">Request telemetry object associated with the current request.</param>
        /// <param name="telemetry">Telemetry item to initialize.</param>
        protected override void OnInitializeTelemetry(
            HttpContext platformContext,
            RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry,
            ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            if (telemetry == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(telemetry));
            if (requestTelemetry == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(requestTelemetry));
            if (platformContext == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(platformContext));
            
            // YOUR CUSTOM LOGIC HERE
            if (platformContext.Session != null)
                requestTelemetry.Properties["CustomUserId"] = platformContext.Session["UserId"].ToString();
        }
}
```

In this custom telemetry initializer I am writing the value of the `UserId` session object in a custom dimension called `CustomUserId`.

##### Custom Telemetry Initializer Registration in Global.asax.cs

```
public class Global : Sitecore.Web.Application
{
        protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new SitecoreSessionInitializer());
        }
}
```

Comment: I know it is not a good practice to modify the `Global.asax.cs` file in a Sitecore installation, but just to use pipelines instead. That is why I registered a `httpRequestProcessed` pipeline, but still had the issues presented above. Either way, I will also try using the OOTB initializer you mentioned and be back with a response. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find a pipeline that was working either. This approach worked for me instead.